# Js Alphabetical sort by attr doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to sort in alphabetical my classes by the attr alt, but it doesn't work and I don't find the error.

```
<div class="box" alt="B"></div>
<div class="box" alt="A"></div>
<div class="box" alt="C"></div>
<div class="box" alt="E"></div>
<div class="box" alt="F"></div>
<div class="box" alt="D"></div>
```

```
var boxes = $('.box');

var orderedBoxes = boxes.sort(function(a, b){
return $(a).attr('alt') - $(b).attr('alt')
});

console.log(orderedBoxes)
```

Comment: Subtraction only works for numbers, not strings.

Comment: Also - not the problem here - the "alt" attribute is only valid on `<img>` elements, which may render your HTML invalid; possibly - again: not related to your problem here - it may be better to use either the `title`, or custom `data-*`, attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.localeCompare`

```js
var boxes = $('.box');

var orderedBoxes = boxes.get().sort(function(a, b){
  return $(a).attr('alt').localeCompare($(b).attr('alt'));
});

console.log(orderedBoxes)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" alt="B"></div>
<div class="box" alt="A"></div>
<div class="box" alt="C"></div>
<div class="box" alt="E"></div>
<div class="box" alt="F"></div>
<div class="box" alt="D"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detach the nodes, sort, and re-append with a simple jQuery plugin.

```js
(function($) {
  function detatchAndSort($nodes, comparator) {
    $nodes.parent().append($nodes.detach().sort(comparator));
    return $nodes;
  };
  $.fn.sortByAttr = function(attr) {
    return detatchAndSort(this, function(that, other) {
      return $(that).attr(attr).localeCompare($(other).attr(attr));
    });
  };
  $.fn.sortByText = function() {
    return detatchAndSort(this, function(that, other) {
      return $(that).text().localeCompare($(other).text());
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.box').sortByAttr('alt'); // Sort in-place
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" alt="B">B</div>
<div class="box" alt="A">A</div>
<div class="box" alt="C">C</div>
<div class="box" alt="E">E</div>
<div class="box" alt="F">F</div>
<div class="box" alt="D">D</div>
```